# UWP InkCanvas: Detecting strokes

Tags: uwp

Trying to use InkCanvas in my UWP app for Windows 10 and have run into a slight problem. I want to make a coloring book app where I can make it so that it won't be possible to draw on the black outlines of the coloring book shapes.

Is this possible? I tried StrokeCollected event, but that did not exist on UWP (only WPF?).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `StrokeCollected` event in `InkCanvas` class.

If you want draw on the black outlines of the coloring book shapes, you can use the [`InkToolbarHighlighterButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inktoolbarhighlighterbutton) in `InkToolbar`. The highlighter draws a semi-transparent stroke with a Rectangle PenTip. It will not cover other stroke.

Please refer Scenario2 of [Simple inking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/f4e92d42dd103a7a2175ba750a89084c1c235d9a/Samples/SimpleInk), it shows how to use InkToolbar functionality in Universal Windows apps.

You can also set the current ink stroke as highlighter by [InkDrawingAttributes.DrawAsHighlighter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkDrawingAttributes#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkDrawingAttributes_DrawAsHighlighter) property.

For example:

```
var drawingAttributes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.CopyDefaultDrawingAttributes();
drawingAttributes.DrawAsHighlighter = true;
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make coloring book app. Then here is a coloring book sample app from Microsoft. Which will help you in customize the inking experience by custom drying the ink input.

> By default, ink input is processed on a low-latency background thread
>   and rendered "wet" as it is drawn. When the stroke is completed (pen
>   or finger lifted, or mouse button released), the stroke is processed
>   on the UI thread and rendered "dry" to the InkCanvas layer (above the
>   application content and replacing the wet ink). Windows Ink enables
>   you to override this behavior and completely customize the inking
>   experience by custom drying the ink input and providing more efficient
>   management of large, or complex, collections of ink strokes.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-coloringbook

Comment: I have edited my answer with why it have been linked.